# How to add marker in android google maps v2 without refreshing the map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

**The problem is when i add markers during the runtime of app  ,the map changes its position**

```
 for (News news : newslist) {
            String inputString=news.getTitle().trim();
            int maxLength = (inputString.length() < MAX_CHAR)?inputString.length():MAX_CHAR;
            inputString = inputString.substring(0, maxLength)+"...";
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(
                    news.getLatitude(),news.getLongitude())).title(inputString).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.world)));
            markersList.add(marker);
        }
```

Comment: What else do you expect ? You are updating you lat and long in each loop and adding the marker there so it will ofcourse the map will change the position

Comment: How to add marker without affecting the map

Comment: Firstly don't add your marker inside the for loop

Comment: i will get  markers depending on the location how to do without for  loop?plz suggest some idea

Comment: See if you update the location coordinates then the map will change its position. And to you want to add multiple markers ? Or you want the marker to keep moving with the updated location coordinates ?